# Modifying OL3 Features from Mapbox Vector Tiles

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I want to modify features from MVT layers, however the modify interaction doesn't work as easily as it does with simple vector layers. The code below does select the feature and it does appear in the modify interaction features property, so I'm not sure what's going wrong:

```js
this.selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
        multi: true
      });

this.modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: this.selectInteraction.getFeatures()
      });

this.map.addInteraction(this.modifyInteraction);
```

My MVT layer is set up like this:

```js
let mapLay = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
          style: styleFunc,
          name: layer.layerid,
        });

let source = new ol.source.VectorTile({
          format: new ol.format.MVT({
            featureClass: ol.Feature
          }),
          projection: 'EPSG:27700',
          tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            maxZoom: 16,
            minZoom: 8,
            tileSize: [1024,1024]
          }),
          tilePixelRatio: 4,
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/vctserv/' + referenceLayer.vct_url + '/{z}/{x}/{y}',
          projection: 'EPSG:3857',
          maxResolution: 1250,
          renderMode: 'vector'
        })
```

I can style and select objects without any issue, but the modify interaction just doesn't seem to trigger. There are no error messages at all.

Any advice on how to allow modification of MVT layers would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to avoid re-requesting the feature via WFS simply so I can modify it.

Many Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that feature geometries in MVT tiles are simplified. You'd be better off getting the original geometry with WFS.

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this issue? Probably nothing to do, but you defined "projection" option twice in VectorTile.

Comment: Well spotted - no I didn't find out, but I didn't really explore this any more. As @ahocevar pointed out, it's better to use WFS geometry for editing, so we have done that.